# React native and Firebase Error 403

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Help, I'm using firebase in my native reagent application, when I test the authentication I get the error 403, someone knows what it can be or how to fix it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVrJr.png)

Please some help :)

Comment: Please include the relevant code and the error in text format in the question instead of linking to an external image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your project does not have access to the necessary google application credentials. Follow this documentation to get started with google cloud authentication: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started.

Comment: Well, I just realized that I restricted the key in the google console that does not add the Identity Toolkit API api